# Are there any specific types or values for which type-punning produces identical behavior in all Standard-conforming C implementations?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, union, portability, type-punning

Type-punning or reinterpreting the underlying bits from one type to another is notorious for having unpredictable and/or non-portable behavior.

For example:

```c
union {
    unsigned u;
    float f;
} c = {.u = 10};
float f = c.f;
```

Not portable, that will depend on the representation of `float`.

---

```c
union {
    unsigned char c[2];
    unsigned short s;
} c = {.c = {1, 2}};
short s = c.s;
```

Not portable, that will depend on the value of `CHAR_BIT` and the byte-order/endian of the system.

---

However, will any of the following have Standard-guaranteed/portable behavior, provided all the `<stdint.h>` types are defined:

```c
union {
    uint8_t b[2];
    uint16_t w;
} c = {.b = {0x18, 0x18}};
assert(c.w == 0x1818);
```

Or the contrary:

```c
union {
    uint8_t b[2];
    uint16_t w;
} c = {.w = 0x1818};
assert(c.b[0] == 0x18 && c.b[1] == 0x18);
```

Or if I extend the size of the types:

```c
union {
    uint16_t w[2];
    uint32_t l;
} c = {.w = {0x1818, 0x1818}};
assert(c.l == 0x18181818);
```

In the above examples, the byte-order does not matter because the number is 'cyclic' and has the same representation in big/little-endian, or in any other esoteric byte-order for that matter. The types are guaranteed to be exactly their specified bits wide and have no trap representations or padding bits.

For those reasons there is no **logical** reason for the type-pun to have non-portable behavior or return any value other than those specified in the `assert()`, but does the C Standard make the same guarantee **explicitly**? Are those examples **truly** portable?

The C Standard states that reading an inactive `union` member will 'reinterpret' the bits to the new type but does that translate to the above examples having portable behavior? Or is there some way by some oddity some technically-conforming C99 implementation could compile but not produce the expected results?

Comment: In theory it should be well defined, but as you stated only for a particular set of values.  Is there a real-world use case for why such a guarantee would be useful?

Comment: @dbush I have some octree code uses type-punning to quickly fill all 8 nodes with values, and check if all 8 nodes a the same value in 3 steps instead of 8, and I can imagine similar use-cases, anytime where you want a dyadic `union` comprising 1 of one integer type, 2 of the half-as-big integer type, 4 of the quarter-size integer type, etc. and want to be able to access any of the individual members or larger members that comprise smaller members.

Comment: I can't find anything saying it wouldn't be ok in C. Are there any particular paragraphs in the standard you are more worried about than others? Set aside: _logical_ assumptions are nullified if the behavior is not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am not really sure what needs clarifying. I said 'provided the `stdint.h` types are defined' thus limiting the scope of the question to systems that **do** support it. And by 'portable' and 'Standard-guaranteed' I mean is there any way, by some stretch, a conforming C99 implementation that supports `stdint.h` could give unexpected results and fail the specified assertion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought 'well-defined' means 'produces the same behavior everywhere' whereas implementation-defined, undefined, or unspecified behaviors are all 'ill-defined' and their behavior varies across implementations, executions, etc. I am not sure what term I should have used instead to mean 'produces the exact same results everywhere.'

Comment: @CPlus: No, “well-defined” means there is a complete unambiguous specification (not an official definition, but my understanding of the term). If I know `a` produces 34 on computers manufactured before 1987 and 57 on computers manufactured after that, it is well defined, even though its use is not portable between the different computers. “Well defined” is about the quality of the definition, not the portability of the code.

Comment: I do not see that the standard requires the `<stdint.h>` types to use particular bits for particular values, either in isolation or correlated with other types, except for the requirement in C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 that value bits in a signed integer type correspond to the value bits in the corresponding unsigned integer type. In other words, `uint16_t` could use bit 0 to designate the value 2^3, bit 1 for 2^7, 2 for 2^9, and so on, and `uint8_t` could be entirely different.

Comment: I might phrase it as “Are there any circumstances for which type-punning produces identical behavior in all standard-conforming C implementations?” (And I might seek to further narrow down “circumstances.”)

Comment: Given the flexibility of the bit value assignments I mention above, all-zero-bit or all-one-bit patterns in two types could be guaranteed to give the same behavior, but any other bit pattern is not guaranteed between two non-corresponding types. There is guaranteed behavior for arbitrary patterns between corresponding signed and unsigned integer types.

Comment: Potential title: “For what types T and U and values V does reinterpreting a value V of type T as type U produce an identical result in all standard-conforming C implementations?” (Note it is not necessary to specify the result be defined or determinate, as, if it is not, it will not be identical in all conforming implementations.) (Also, here we allow T or U to be array types, taking their value to be an ordered type of element values.) Fine title for mathematicians, but I suppose others will want the plainer English title. But the question could be posed that way in the body.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I feel that might do better in the question body, as a clarification for circumstances, as that title would be a bit long.

Comment: However, we can consider `!! (union { uint8_t a[2]; uint16_t b; }) { 0x18, 0x18 } .b` to be an answer. In other words, although we cannot know the value of the `b` member due to the bit-value problem, we do know it is non-zero, so all implementations will produce 1 for the expression. Similarly, the count of bits in `b` will equal the count of bits in `a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I knew about byte-order but I never realized bit-order could be a problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type-punning refers to reinterpreting a **representation** of a type as another type. If types are guaranteed to have the same or sufficiently well-defined representations, then type-punning may be portable.

This is confirmed explicitly in [6.2.5 Footnote 39](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (Emphasis mine):

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and **members of unions.**

#### Integers

> For signed integer types [...] Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the **object representation** of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value.

This means that any positive `unsigned` value of a type less than or equal to the maximum positive value of the corresponding `signed` type will have the same value when type-punned, and vice versa, since all the corresponding bits in the representation must have the same effect on the final value.

This is guaranteed explicitly:

> A valid (non-trap) object representation of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value.

Additionally:

> For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.

Any value with all bits 0 has a value of 0. Therefore, any part of any all-0 integer type can be type-punned to any smaller integer, or multiple smaller integers with all bits 0 (including padding bits if any) may be type-punned to a larger one, and the value **will still be 0**.

**This partially addresses the examples in the question, as we know the fixed-width types have no padding bits, so those examples *shall work* with values of 0.**

#### Fixed-width integers (if defined)

Type-punning `intN_t` to `uintN_t` for the same `N` will be equivalent to adding `2^(N-1)` to the value **if** the `intN_t` value is negative. The reverse will be equivalent to subtracting `2^(N-1)` from the value **if** the `uintN_t` value is greater than the maximum value of `intN_t`.

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

This requirement guarantees that there are no padding bits and, since they have the same total number of bits, the number of **value** bits in the `intN_t` **must be one** less than the number of **value** bits in the `uintN_t`.

> there shall be exactly one sign bit.

And since all 15 value bits in the `intN_t` must have the same values as the corresponding bits in the representation of `uintN_t`, and that two's complement is required for all fixed width types, by process of elimination **the sign bit in `intN_t` must correspond to the value bit with value `2^N-1` in the `uintN_t`.** Thus, type-punning between them must have portable behavior as specified above.

#### Pointers

In [6.2.5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

This implies one can safely type-pun between `void *` and `char *`, or between any two `struct` pointers, or any two `union` pointers, or between any two pointers to compatible (e.g., signed and unsigned versions of the same type) types. Although one can convert any object pointer type to `void *` or `char *`, doing so would require an explicit cast, not a type-pun.

#### Structures

Type-punning between structures and other structures or types is generally non-portable, due to the unspecified amount of padding inserted between structure members. However there are some exceptions:

In [6.5.2.3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

Type-punning is portable between a structure and the first member of the structure, or between a union and any of the members in the union, provided the behavior of type-punning the member with the last-stored member of the union has portable behavior.

> A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

Additionally:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the complete type of the union is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

This means if you have several separate structure types but all of their first members are of compatible types and in the same order, their matching members may be type-punned/accessed so long as at the scope of accessing, a `union` is fully declared and visible both. Example from the [C Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The following is a valid fragment:
>
> ```
> union {
>    struct {
>        int alltypes;
>    } n;
>    struct {
>        int type;
>        int intnode;
>    } ni;
>    struct {
>        int type;
>        double doublenode;
>    } nf;
> } u;
> u.nf.type = 1;
> u.nf.doublenode = 3.14;
> /* ... */
> if (u.n.alltypes == 1)
>    if (sin(u.nf.doublenode) == 0.0)
>        /* ... */
> ```
>
> The following is not a valid fragment (because the union type is not visible within function f):
>
> ```
> struct t1 { int m; };
> struct t2 { int m; };
> int f(struct t1 *p1, struct t2 *p2)
> {
>    if (p1->m < 0)
>    p2->m = -p2->m;
>    return p1->m;
> }
> int g()
> {
>    union {
>        struct t1 s1;
>        struct t2 s2;
>    } u;
>    /* ... */
>    return f(&u.s1, &u.s2);
> }
> ```

#### Union between arrays of smaller fixed-width types and larger fixed-width types

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of **contiguous** sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.

This means that, provided there are no padding bits (which is the case for fixed-width types), type punning between two consecutive types to one twice as big will be guaranteed to have the effect of concatenating the bits of their object representations. **Contiguous** implies there can be no 'junk' between raw bytes in memory.

> For unsigned integer types [...] objects of that type shall be capable of
> representing values from 0 to `2^N − 1` using a pure binary representation;

But does *pure binary notation* guarantee that the value bits in the object representation are ordered, increasingly, by magnitude?

Pure binary notation is defined as:

> A **positional representation** for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by **successive bits** are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position. (Adapted from the American National Dictionary for Information Processing Systems.) A byte contains CHAR_BIT bits, and the values of type unsigned char range from 0 to 2CHAR_BIT − 1.

This explicitly mentions the **representation, successive bits, and position.** This implies that the bits in pure binary notation are ordered starting lowest to highest. If this [were not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212825/are-there-any-circumstances-specific-types-values-for-which-type-punning-produ#comment137886904_78212825), and the exact position of the bit within the representational would be meaningless, and the definition would not mention the position or that the bits are successive, that each of the value bits exist and correspond to each power of 2 between 0 and N. However, this definition specifies that the bits are successive and ordered.

Why the requirement that bits signed integers have the same values as corresponding bits in unsigned values, if that would be redundant? Most likely, to make sure that the placement of the padding and/or sign bit does not 'offset' the value bits relative to a corresponding signed type.

Given the above, concatenating identical copies of a fixed number of ordered bits into a new fixed number of ordered bits must produce the same value each time. A case could be made that any implementation that does not demonstrate the expected behavior in that case would violate the definition of *pure binary notation.*